# Busy Indicator SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5, busyindicator

I want to include a busy indicator whenever someone clicks on "Save" button. I had written code following the examples on Demo kit. It works fine when only few items are in the cart, but if there are plenty of items in the cart, the busy indicator shows after the Odata call is over and after Order is successfully placed. Busy indicator is not shown immediately on button press. Any idea why this happens ?

```
hideBusyIndicator : function() {
            sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
        },

showBusyIndicator : function (iDuration, iDelay) {
            sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show(iDelay);

            if (iDuration && iDuration > 0) {
                if (this._sTimeoutId) {
                    jQuery.sap.clearDelayedCall(this._sTimeoutId);
                    this._sTimeoutId = null;
                }

                this._sTimeoutId = jQuery.sap.delayedCall(iDuration, this, function() {
                    this.hideBusyIndicator();
                });
            },


onSaveButtonPressed: function() 
{
 this.showBusyIndicator(4000, 0);
},
```

Comment: What version of UI5 and ODataModel are you using?

Comment: Using version 1.52.4 for UI5, dunno how to check version for OData.

Comment: Which module did you use to instantiate the ODataModel? `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`, `v2.ODataModel`, or `v4.ODataModel`?

Comment: Is this behavior still reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Normaly busy indicaotr doesn't works for ajax/odata call less than 1 sec.

For this use

sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show(**0**)

Pass '0' to start it immediately **and make sure all odata calls are a-synchronous**.

Comment: I checked, it has parameter "true" in Odata.Create function. In debug when I see I can clearly see busy indicator starting but other wise no. Is there any other way to ensure that when we click save many times, not multiple orders are created. I tried to disable the button but same thing. it gets disabled after the call.

Comment: Can you please share complete code your onPress of "Create" button?
Or otherwise try using setTimeOut